# How to select data based on months using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in php and making a small online banking system in php for my College project. I wanted to generate the statement for each month. I'm recording each transaction happening in each days. I wanted to retrieve rows from the table till the end of each month beginning from the starting of the account. So If I click on the view statement link, (considering that I opened the account on 14th of Feb) I need to see two statements. 1 from 14th of Feb to 28th of Feb and another one from 1st of March to current date.

What mysql query should I used to get this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a select with a where and order by clauses.

Comment: What format are that dates stored in your sql database?

Comment: `$date=date("Y-m-d")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try appending to your current query the condition for the current month, you can `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, etc... to the `AND MONTH...` condition.

```
AND
YEAR(`date_column`) = YEAR(NOW())
AND MONTH(`date_column`) = MONTH(NOW())
```

where `date_column` is the name of the column you are working. It might also be that you are trying to `GROUP BY`MONTH(`date_column`)` its a bit hard to tell.